# Symfony: The file .../config_.yml does not exist

Tags: php, symfony

When trying to run the server in the command line with `php  app/console server:run --env=prod` I get:

> [InvalidArgumentException]
>   The file
>   "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sym/firstApp/app/config/config_.yml" does
>   not exist.

Tried all the tips I could google for, which are not that many. Somehow the environment is not set. The project is still nearly new created; I'm doing the [tutorial](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/page_creation.html).

Some history: After making a template, I had the popular `can't create /cache/ directory` Exception. I had to set the directory for cache and log manually (with `getCacheDir()` and `getLogDir()` in AppKernel) because all the `chmod` etc. didn't work. When I ran the command with `sudo` /cache/ was created at the top level (`/`). So I think the project directory isn't set properly too.

Using symfony installer 1.1.7, PHP 5.5.27, Max OS X.

Comment: "because all the chmod etc. didn't work" - at least one must work http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#book-installation-permissions , but it looks like you changed path to `config.yml` file in loader (in AppKernel.php or something)

Comment: The environment is not see properly (it should load the `config_(dev|prod|test).yml` file). Have you tried with `php  app/console server:run --env=dev`?

Comment: @malcolm Some directory was set wrong. Because of the permission issue I once tried `sudo php app/console ...` and it made a `/cache/` directory in the root level of my system. That's why I set the directories manually.

Comment: @A.L yes I do that. The funny thing: I copied `config_dev.yml` to `config_.yml` to see what happens and it gives me an `There is no extension able to load the configuration for "web_profiler"`, so I removed that from the config file. After that I get an `A string value must be composed of strings and/or numbers, but found parameter "kernel.environment" of type NULL i  
  nside string value "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log". ` I think I'm going to set up a new environment.

Answer (score 1):

Try to clear your cache with this command line :

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

because you are trying to run symfony in production mode.